# Node, MongoDB (mongoose) distinct count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, count, mongoose, distinct

I have a collection with multiple documents and every one of them has and 'eID' field that is not unique. I want to get the count for all the distinct 'eID'.

Example: if there are 5 documents with the 'eID' = ObjectID(123) and 2 documents with 'eID' = ObjectID(321) I want to output something like:

```
{
   ObjectID(123): 5,
   ObjectID(321): 2
}
```

I don't know if that can be done in the same query but after knowing what are the most ocurring eID's I want to fetch the referenced documents using the ObjectID

Mongoose version 3.8.8

Answer (score 4):

$status is the specific field of collection that i need to count distinct number of element.

```
          var agg = [
            {$group: {
              _id: "$status",
              total: {$sum: 1}
            }}
          ];

          model.Site.aggregate(agg, function(err, logs){
            if (err) { return res.json(err); }

            return res.json(logs);
          });

//output
[
  {
    "_id": "plan",
    "total": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": "complete",
    "total": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": "hault",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "incomplete",
    "total": 4
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not in terms of how this query can be written via mongoose, but I am familiar with the nodejs MongoClient class if you have further questions regarding implementation.

The best (most optimal) way I can think of doing this is to use mapReduce or aggregation on your database. The closest thing to a single command would be the **distinct** command, which can be invoked on collections, but this will only give you an array of distinct values for the **eID** key.

See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

For your specific problem, you will want your map and reduce functions roughly as follows:

`var map = function() {
        var value = 1;
        emit(this.eID, value);
    };
    var reduce = function(key, values) {
        var result = 0;
        for(var i=-1;++i<values.length;){
            var value = values[i];
            result += value;
        };
        return result;
    };`

There might be an easier way to do this using the aggregation pipeline (I would post the link but I don't have enough reputation).

I also found the mapReduce command for mongoose: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.mapReduce